# How to set VERSION-LEVEL IMMUTABILITY SUPPORT property of Azure storage Container using .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, immutability

I am trying to set VERSION-LEVEL IMMUTABILITY SUPPORT property of container as below (C# with .Net Core) but none of them is setting this property to enabled. First and second are adding as metadata key pair and third one is erroring out with "errorMessage":"Unable to add header to request or content"}

#1

```
IDictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "immutableStorageWithVersioning", "enabled" } };
// Creating new container
BlobContainerClient container = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName, PublicAccessType.None, metadata);
```

#2

```
IDictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "EnableImmutableStorageWithVersioning", "enabled" } };
// Creating new container
BlobContainerClient container = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName, PublicAccessType.None, metadata);
```

#3

```
IDictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "VERSION-LEVEL IMMUTABILITY SUPPORT", "enabled" } };
// Creating new container
BlobContainerClient container = await blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName, PublicAccessType.None, metadata);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way I can set that property? I could not find any Azure documentation to set this property except using Azure CLI or Powershell.

I tried above mentioned 3 options but none of them is setting the property to Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the metadata on the container which are user defined key/value pairs, and they do not have any impact on the Azure Blob Container.

What you need to do is to set a system property that refers to the version-level immutability support, unfortunately that property is not exposed for set operation via the Azure Storage SDK. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-properties-metadata) shows ways to read system properties but no options to write the same. Please see difference between metadata and system properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata).

One possible solution, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-policy-configure-version-scope?tabs=azure-portal#configure-a-default-time-based-retention-policy), is to configure a default version-level policy for the storage account after the storage account is created, this policy applies by default to all new blob versions that are created in that account.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this feature does not exist in Azure SDK, I see there is feature request here using terraform - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/21512. Also, your possible solution link shows how to configure a default version-level immutability policy for a storage account or container, use the Azure portal, PowerShell, Azure CLI, or one of the Azure Storage SDKs but that also requires that you have enabled support for version-level immutability for the storage account or container. This translates into chicken and egg problem.

Comment: If you set the immutability at account level with a default policy using portal/PS/CLI, then all containers created under the account from anywhere would adhere to that policy definition, right? I do not understand the challenge with the suggested approach.

Comment: I am looking for setting this either using terraform or using Azure SDK and I could not find any possible solution.

Comment: @kaish You could try using the `local-exec` provisioner to call the Azure CLI command `az storage container immutability-policy ...`